# Why is Bloc skipping this emit command?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, bloc

I have an bloc that receives an event called OpenTourStop that invokes a function whose first line of code invokes `emit(Waiting());` and then proceeds to execute some logic before emitting a different state. In the UI, the BlocConsumer is supposed to print out a message to the console as soon as state equals Waiting, but it NEVER does. The bloc does not emit the Waiting state, but does emit the other states that result from completing the function. What am I doing wrong?

Below are the relevant sections of code for the bloc and UI

Bloc code:

```
class QuiztourManagerBloc
    extends Bloc<QuiztourManagerEvent, QuiztourManagerState> {
  final QuiztourRemoteData _repo;

  QuiztourManagerBloc({QuiztourRemoteData repo})
      : _repo = repo,
        super(QuiztourManagerInitial()) {
    on<OpenTourStop>(_openTourStop);
  }

  _openTourStop(event, emit) {
    emit(Waiting()); // Why doesn't the Waiting state show up in the UI?
    final _tourStopIndex = event.tourStopIndex;

// section of code removed for clarity

    if (_quizPlayDoc.seenRules && tourStopGameResults.isEmpty) {
      emit(ShowQuizQuestionViewManager(
          quizPlayDoc: _quizPlayDoc, tourStopIndex: _tourStopIndex));
      // emit(ShowQuizQuestions(quizPlayDoc: _quizPlayDoc, tourStopIndex: _tourStopIndex));
    } else if (tourStopGameResults.length > 0) {
      emit(ShowQuizTourStopScreen(
        tour: event.tour,
        tourStopIndex: event.tourStopIndex,
        quizPlayDoc: _quizPlayDoc,
        maxTourStopPoints: _maxTourStopPoints.toString(),
        pointsEarned: _tourStopScore.toString(),
      ));
    } else {
      emit(ShowQuizRules(_quizPlayDoc));
    }
  }

}
```

UI code (from class QuizTourStopViewManager) :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return BlocConsumer<QuiztourManagerBloc, QuiztourManagerState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is Waiting) {
          print('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  Waiting '); // Why does this line never get executed?
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        }
        
        else if (state is ShowQuizTourStopScreen) {
          return QuizTourStop( );
        } 
      },
      listener: (_, state) {},
    );
  }
```

The UI that triggers the event is a button. The code associated with that button is below:

```
onTap: () => Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              if (tourType == "quizTour") {
                BlocProvider.of<QuiztourManagerBloc>(context)
                  .add(OpenTourStop(
                    tour: tour,
                    tourStopIndex: selectedTourStopIndex,
                  ));
                return QuizTourStopViewManager(
                  tour: tour,
                  // game: widget.game,
                  selectedTourStopIndex: selectedTourStopIndex,
                );
```

Comment: May I know code that the 'OpenTourStop' event is called?

Comment: I just edited the original question to include the onTap that triggers the event. The BlocConsumer is found in the QuizTourStopViewer class is returned by the onTap. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that when you send 'OpenTourStop' event at 'onTap' method,
 'QuizTourStopViewManager' page is not builded.

So would you try to change event call position after 'OpenTourStop' page is builded?

- At initState() method inside.

  or
- At 'bloc' parameter in BlocConsumer method.